# Can i get export FreePBX+Asterisk CPU,RAM and other monitoring info in csv or other file?

Tags: csv, export, asterisk, voip, pbx

I have FreePBX 12.0.64 installed, how can i monitor system resources by date or every hour?
Are there some tools for exporting this statistic to a text or csv file for future filtering? (I'm interested in CPU, RAM, HDD (temp and usage)) 
Asterisk filtering: total calls, inbound, outbound, total time.

Are there any tools to monitor this or any existing modules?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need nagios/centreon setup or create special module for freepbx

Freepbx not store such info nor monitor it.